# "No sooner had" vs "as soon as" vs "scarcely had"

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

1. > No sooner had we sat down, the phone rang.
2. > As soon as we sat down, the phone rang.
3. > Scarcely had we sat down, the phone rang.

Is any difference in meaning among them? Are they correct grammatically?

Comment: "The phone *rang*", not *ranged*.

Answer (score 1):

So, combining the corrections in the first two answers, only your #2 is correct grammatically:

- 1  No sooner had we sat down, **than** the phone rang.
- 2  As soon as we sat down, the phone rang. (ok as-is)
- 3  Scarcely had we sat down, **when** the phone rang.

The third has a bit more of a formal register.  You would more likely encounter it in literature than in conversation.  More likely you would hear "We had {just/barely/scarcely} sat down, when the phone rang."

Answer (score 0):

The construct is "no sooner .. than ..", so the first sentence ought to be

> No sooner had we sat down than the phone rang.

The second and third sentences are fine grammatically as is.

The difference in meaning exists between "*as soon as* .." and "*scarcely* .." I believe.  In the case of "*as soon as*", the phone rang *at the moment* the last person's bottom touched the chair.  In the case of "*scarcely*" some (little) time passed between "we sat down" and the ringing of the phone, although not a significant amount.